# Add GPS tags in libtiff

Tags: c, gps, tiff, luajit, libtiff

I need to add GPS metadata to TIFF / DNG images using LibTIFF. I know very little about LibTIFF. To be extra annoying, I have to hack this into an existing LuaJIT module with minimal footprint (Edit: to be clear, I don't need an answer in LuaJIT!).

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959617/in-a-tiff-create-a-sub-ifd-with-thumbnail-libtiff#11998400), it seems like I need to set the TIFFTAG_SUBIFD field first, then write the main IFD, then write the GPS IFD. I'm confused on two points:

1. There's a special LibTIFF name for TIFFTAG_GPSIFD, and I'm not sure where that comes in, or if that's supposed to happen in place of setting TIFFTAG_SUBIFD.
2. I don't know how to assemble the GPS IFD in the first place. If indeed I'm supposed to set TIFFTAG_SUBIFD and use TIFFWriteDirectory() to close the main IFD, I assume that any following calls to TIFFSetField() will write to the GPS IFD, but there are no LibTIFF names for the fields inside the GPS IFD. That makes me think I'm missing something.

I imagine it's clear that I don't really know what I'm doing with LibTIFF, so any help is appreciated. Feel free to ignore the fact that I'm in LuaJIT and just tell me what this might look like in C.

For reference, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371620/how-to-add-gps-metadata-to-tiff-in-java) seems to accomplish the same task in Java, but I don't understand it well enough to translate.

Finally, here's a general idea of what I have now, but this is obviously incomplete. the "v_int" style functions are just helpers to return the appropriate C variable from ffi.new().

```
local fdt = tiff.TIFFOpen(ofname, 'w')

-- Set all the fields in the main IFD here
-- ...

if self.scfg.gps then
    -- Prepare libtiff for a subIFD
    -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959617/in-a-tiff-create-a-sub-ifd-with-thumbnail-libtiff#11998400
    subifd_n = v_int(1)
    subifd_offsets = ffi.new(string.format('toff_t[%i]', subifd_n), {v_uint32(0)})
    tiff.TIFFSetField(fdt, C.TIFFTAG_SUBIFD, v_int(subifd_n), subifd_offsets)
end

local bytes_per_pixel = self.sample_depth / 8
tiff.TIFFWriteRawStrip(fdt, 0, data_raw, self.frame_height * self.frame_width * bytes_per_pixel)

if self.scfg.gps then
    tiff.TIFFWriteDirectory(fdt)    -- Finish main IFD
    b2 = v_unit8(2)
    b0 = v_uint8(0)
    tiff.TIFFSetField(fdt, 0, b2, b2, b0, b0)   -- GPSVersionID
end

tiff.TIFFClose(fdt)   -- Closes currently-open IFD (?)
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: FWIW all your statements so far sound correct

Comment: _"there are no LibTIFF names for the fields inside the GPS IFD"_ doesn't matter just  use [the tag IDs](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/GPS.html)